# asp.net core binder doesn't work if object have more than 20 properties 0_o

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, binding

I have .cshtml page , it has model List
Class Indications have 20 properties. My form

```
    @model List<Indications>


<body>

 <div> 
       <form asp-action="EditFlatLight" asp-controller="Home"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="container">
         
            
          
        @for (int i=0; i<Model.Count();i++)
        {

       
         var indication = Model[i].GetType().GetProperty(ViewBag.Title).GetValue(Model[i], null).ToString();
         var data = ViewBag.Title;
         
         <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <label>@Model[i].FlatNumber</label>
          </div>
          
         

          <div class="column">
              <input type="text" class="row" value="@indication" asp-for="@Model[i].Month" tabIndex="@i">
          </div>      
           
           <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden"   value="@ViewBag.Title" asp-for="@Model[i].Type"/>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].Id" asp-for="@Model[i].Id"/>
           </div>
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].Login" asp-for="@Model[i].Login"/>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].City" asp-for="@Model[i].City"/>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].Street" asp-for="@Model[i].Street"/>
           </div>
              <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].HouseNumber" asp-for="@Model[i].HouseNumber"/>
           </div>
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].January" asp-for="@Model[i].January"/>
           </div> 
           <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].February" asp-for="@Model[i].February"/>
           </div>
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].March" asp-for="@Model[i].March"/>
           </div> 
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].April" asp-for="@Model[i].April"/>
           </div> 
           <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].May" asp-for="@Model[i].May"/>
           </div>  
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].June" asp-for="@Model[i].June"/>
           </div> 
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].July" asp-for="@Model[i].July"/>
           </div> 
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].August" asp-for="@Model[i].August"/>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].September" asp-for="@Model[i].September"/>
           </div> 
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].October" asp-for="@Model[i].October"/>
           </div> 
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].November" asp-for="@Model[i].November"/>
           </div> 
            <div class="column">
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model[i].December" asp-for="@Model[i].December"/>
           </div>
           </div>
        } 

           
        <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:5px">Save</button>


        </form>
   
   
 </div>
  
</body>
```

And if i try to pass data to controller with all parameters it return null, but if try to pass least than 20 parameters, i receive full list, please, help....
Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(IEnumerable<Indications> newData)
        {
        }
```

I fight with this problem whole week. I really don't understand why i get null with more than 20 properties 0_0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I try the code you provided, It works fine, you need to provide `Indications` and `httpget method` code

Comment: Do you try to pass more than 20 parameters?

Comment: Yes, It can receive data normally.